# auto open_flags = std::ios::binary; seems to produce the wrong type in MSVC. Is it a bug?

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++, c++17, msvc12

This c++ code compiles fine with gcc, icc, and clang, but fails with MSVC:

```
#include <ios>

int main()
{
    auto open_flags = std::ios::binary;
    open_flags |= std::ios::app;

    return 0;
}
```

> (6): error C2678: binary '|=': no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'std::_Iosb::_Openmode' (or there is no acceptable conversion)

https://godbolt.org/z/999fffPEx

Changing the code to this gives a more helpful error message:

```
#include <ios>

int main()
{
    auto open_flags = std::ios::binary;
    open_flags = open_flags | std::ios::app;

    return 0;
}
```

> (6): error C2440: '=': cannot convert from 'int' to 'std::_Iosb::_Openmode'

And this compiles fine:

```
#include <ios>

int main()
{
    auto open_flags = std::ios::binary | std::ios::out;
    open_flags = open_flags | std::ios::app;

    return 0;
}
```

This looks like incorrect behaviour to me. Like MSVC has implemented the | operator with return type int instead of ios::openmode.

It's also worth noting that the original code compiles if I use std::ios::openmode instead of auto, presumably through implicit conversion.

Is this an MSVC bug, or am I missing something? Standards references welcome!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a MSVC bug.

According to the standard:

1. `binary` has type `std::ios_base::openmode` ([[ios.base.general]](http://eel.is/c++draft/ios.base.general));
2. `std::ios_base::openmode` is a bitmask type ([[ios.openmode]](http://eel.is/c++draft/ios.openmode)).

But on MSVC:

1. [`binary` has an enum type (the internal type `_Openmode`)](https://github.com/microsoft/STL/blob/main/stl/inc/xiosbase#L75), but [`std::ios_base::openmode` is `int`](https://github.com/microsoft/STL/blob/main/stl/inc/xiosbase#L177).
2. `_Openmode` is not a bitmask type (and thus only built-in operators `|`, `&`, `^`, `~` are applicable).

Please file a bug report (or two) at https://github.com/microsoft/STL.

Comment: Bug report filed, thanks. Should be an interesting experience. Thankfully it seems like the most straightforward bug I could hope to come accross ;-).
https://github.com/microsoft/STL/issues/3401